# multiple find conditions in one query not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to run a query on mongodb from my node js code. query is to get documents which are between the date range and matches the user id which is part of document.

i have tried below queries. none of them work. But if i query only date it works or if i query only userId it works. combination doesn't work.

my document structure is as follows :

```
{
_id: 5d7e5dd0a7eef002f486863a,
userId: 5d7e5dd0a7eef002f4868639,
date: 2019-09-15T15:50:40.250Z,
...
},
{
_id: 5d862abf6d083d24c06adbb8,
userId: 5d86684f84adde0120ad5023,
date: 2019-09-21T13:50:55.010Z,
...
}
```

Queries i tried are

```
db.collection.find({"date":{'$gte':ISODate('2019-09-14T18:03:13.525Z'),'$lt':ISODate('2019-09-21T18:03:13.525Z')},"userId":ObjectId("5d86684f84adde0120ad5023")})

{$and:[{"date":{'$gte':ISODate('2019-09-14T18:03:13.525Z'),'$lt':ISODate('2019-09-21T20:03:13.525Z')}},{userId:ObjectId("5d86684f84adde0120ad5023")}]}

db.collection.aggregate([
                    { $match: { userId: ObjectId("5d86684f84adde0120ad5023"), date :{'$gte':ISODate('2019-09-14T18:03:13.525Z'),'$lt':ISODate('2019-09-21T20:03:13.525Z')} } }])
```

i am expecting documents to be returned whose dates falls in between the range and whose userId is also a match.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the dates `date` field in the documents stored as date object? Or strings?

Comment: its stored as date object only `new Date().toISOString()`

Comment: Well that's your problem. Those are **not** BSON Dates ( as the `ISODate()` function is producing, which is really just the same as `Date` for the shell ) but are in fact now **"strings"**, since that what `toISOString()` is doing. You really should have stored simply as `new Date()` **only**.

Comment: You basically *now* need: `.find({ "date": { "$gte": '2019-09-14T18:03:13.525Z' , "$lte": '2019-09-21T18:03:13.525Z' }, "userId": ObjectId("5d86684f84adde0120ad5023") })` in order to match based on **"strings"**. And *possibly* similarly ignoring the `ObjectId` if you similarly called `toString()` when storing.

Comment: FYI. If you are using MongoDB 4.2 or greater you can *fix your data* with a quick update statement. i.e `db.collection.updateMany({}, [{ "$set": { "date": { "$toDate": "$date" } } }])`. This uses the new *aggregation pipeline syntax* in order to apply the `$toDate` method and convert the "strings" to actual BSON Dates. Then your original query attempts will indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

The below query seems to work just fine, for finding documents based on $and operator :

```
db.getCollection('transactionlogs').find({$and:[{"createdAt":{'$gte':ISODate('2018-11-17T12:17:00Z'),'$lt':ISODate('2019-09-21T20:03:13.525Z')}},{_id:ObjectId("5bf006e3519f46d2eb075959")}]})
```

The reason that you might not be getting expected results is that, the above query will at most return 1 record only. Since, the ObjectId attribute is going to be "highly likely" unique.

Comment: OP is not asking to search on `_id` ( which is of course unique ) but `userid`. The actual problem is quite evident due to the OP's own comment.